# @Input angular 2 pass number or object variables

Tags: javascript, angular

It is possible to send number or a whole class instance to @Input ?
I am trying to  send the value  like this `value="id"` or this `[value]="id"`. 
for example `id = 1`.But in console i see that my object received string value `id` and not the value of id, those = 1.
In console i see this:

```
 id :  id
    typeof:  string
```

**UPDATED**

My class that store value:

```
private id: number ;

  show(id: number): void { 
    this.id = id;
  }
```

In html page of my component i assign to selector of my childComponent value  like this `value="id"` or this `[value]="id"`.

And my child class is very simple:

```
 @Input() value: number;
  constructor() { 
  }
  　
  　ngOnChanges() {
  　  console.log(`ngOnChanges: `, this.value);
  　}
```

Comment: can you post your tries, it can help us to understand the problem more clearly

Comment: The simple answer to your question is "yes". But to help you with syntax, we'll need to see your code.

Comment: If you pass value="id" here id is a string a variable but if you pass value = id may be depend of your context, simple description, simple answer. Regards

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> It is possible to send number or a whole class instance to @Input ?

Yes, it is possible.

**Notes:**

1. For Number and boolean variables you can pass them around as [value]="12" and [value]="true".
2. For passing strings, you need to enclose the string within single quotes to pass them as it is. `[value]="'Justastring'"`.
3. For object or variables defined in the component, you can simply pass them.

For @Input() bound attributes, the common way is `[value]="id"`.

Angular will now simply look for variable named id in the component's class and assign the value to the value variable in the child component.

Comment: Would be good if you could update this with an example for #3 for consistency (i.e all the other two have an example, and the third one doesn't.